# How to use URL schemes to open another Application from my Application in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

What I want is, to open another application from my Xamarin Forms application in iOS. I read about URL schemes in iOS, but how to implement that in Xamarin Applications. I am using dependency service to call native functions. I have done that in Android and works perfectly.

I found a link 
https://riccardo-moschetti.org/2014/10/03/opening-a-mobile-app-from-a-link-the-xamarin-way-url-schemas/. But it uses Xamarin Studio and i am using Visual Studio and VS2015 does not have this option.

Anyone has a better solution for this?

Comment: u can get xml version of info.plist in both IDEs . copy and paste ,
that should solve ur problem

Comment: But I will have to copy the solution to MAC, because the Xamarin doesn't support iOS development on windows.

Comment: it does support , u just need to have a mac for build !

Comment: It doesn't bro. Have a look at it. Xamarin does not support iOS developement on **Windows**

Comment: i meant , u can use visual studio community !

Comment: That's what I said the designer in info.plist in Visual studio does not contain anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by adding the below key in the info.plist in the application I want to open.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.example.ios</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>testscheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And then using the below code to open the application

```
if(!UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("testscheme://com.example.ios")))
{
//Use the code below to go to itunes if application not found.
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("itms://itunes.apple.com/in/app/appname/appid")); 
}
```

Comment: I am handling url similar way. But when my application is already opened then opening application from link stops application and starts again. Is it normal? Do you know how to open link without killing application?